# Obtener query por intervalo de horas postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

Veran, tengo una tabla llamada `tiempos` con un `id` y un `horario`  que va de  la siguiente manera

```
id horarios
1  06:00
2  07:00
3  08:00
4  09:00
5  10:00 
6  11:00
7  12:00
```

lo que intento hacer es por medio de una consulta sql traer todas las horas que esten en un `intervalo de tiempo por ejemplo de 2 horas` iniciando desde las `06:00`, es decir que la consulta me muestre algo como

```
06:00
08:00
10:00
12:00
```

¿Sera esto posible?, yo este problema que presento lo tengo resuelto en código pero creo que debe de haber una forma mucho mas optima haciéndolo directamente en la base de datos pero aun no he encontrado solucion para ello, agradecería mucho el interés.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción que se me ocurre, para poder trabajar con intervalos horarios, es usar generate_series.

Para ello, los datos de tiempo, deben ser timestamp, no es posible con time.

Parece que la columna horarios la tienes de tipo text, por eso hago una primera conversión a timestamp, poniendo una fecha cualquiera, genero la serie según el intervalo deseado, y luego quito la parte date, dejando solo la hora como en la tabla origen.

```
select 
substring(generate_series(('2020-12-18 ' || min(horarios))::timestamp
                         ,('2020-12-18 ' || max(horarios))::timestamp
                         ,interval '2 hour')::text, 12, 5) AS horarios
from    
    tiempos
where  
    horarios in (select horarios from tiempos);
```

Lo he probado con una tabla igual a la tuya y funciona bien, para distintos intervalos y distintos horarios inicio y fin.
Espero te sirva tal cual, o por lo menos te de una idea de como abordarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que crees una tabla de estructura en la cual esten cada registro del rango de hpra que desees esto con la finalidad que si no hay un rango de tiempo dentro de los datos igualmente este registro aparezca en tu consulta.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).